# How to deal with messy data - with variables not marked as missing

Tags: r, tidyr, data-cleaning, spread

My data is quite messy but for most part, it looks something like this, with a repeating sequence of 9 categories:

```
9   TI: Prize Structure and Information in Tournaments: Experimental Evidence
10  AU: Freeman, Richard B.; Gelber, Alexander M.
11  AF: NBER; NBER
12  SO: American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2(1), January 2010, pp. 149-64
13  IS: 1945-7782
14  AV: http://www.aeaweb.org/aej-applied/
15  DT: Journal Article
16  PY: 2010
17  AN: 1075725
```

However, some of the sequences are lacking certain variables/variable numbers **which are not marked as NA**. An example would be the very first sequence, lacking the title (TI:)-variable:

```
1   AU: Duflo, Esther
2   AF: MIT
3   SO: American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2(2), April 2010, pp.
4   IS: 1945-7782
5   AV: http://www.aeaweb.org/aej-applied/
6   DT: Journal Article
7   PY: 2010
8   AN: 1094392
```

Every sequence (or so I gather) will end with Article Number (AN). Apart from this, variables/variable values seem to be missing pretty much at random.

If I use ordinary methods (assigning ID-numbers by group and then the spread function) this would change the order in my data, causing the title for the second sequence to appear in the first, and so forth. I want to make the data appear in this format, with 'NA' for each missing variable value in each sequence:

```
Sequence    TI:   AU:   AF:   SO:   IS:   AV:   DT:   PY:    AN:       
    1      'NA'  Duflo MIT   AEJ   1945  aea   jour  2010   1094392
    2       Priz Freem NBER  AEJ   1945  aea   jour  2010   1075725
```

Is there any way I can do this with normal r functions?

I don't know if this will help (this data is quite regular) but I'll attach the first 27 observations:

```
structure(list(category = c("AU:", "AF:", "SO:", "IS:", "AV:", 
"DT:", "PY:", "AN:", "TI:", "AU:", "AF:", "SO:", "IS:", "AV:", 
"DT:", "PY:", "AN:", "TI:", "AU:", "AF:", "SO:", "IS:", "AV:", 
"DT:", "PY:", "AN:", "TI:"), value = c("Duflo, Esther", "MIT", 
"American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2(2), April 2010, pp.", 
"1945-7782", "http://www.aeaweb.org/aej-applied/", "Journal Article", 
"2010", "1094392", "Prize Structure and Information in Tournaments: Experimental Evidence", 
"Freeman, Richard B.; Gelber, Alexander M.", "NBER; NBER", "American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2(1), January 2010, pp. 149-64", 
"1945-7782", "http://www.aeaweb.org/aej-applied/", "Journal Article", 
"2010", "1075725", "Why Have College Completion Rates Declined? An Analysis of Changing Student Preparation and Collegiate Resources", 
"Bound, John; Lovenheim, Michael F.; Turner, Sarah", "U MI; Cornell U; U VA", 
"American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2(3), July 2010, pp. 129-57", 
"1945-7782", "http://www.aeaweb.org/aej-applied/", "Journal Article", 
"2010", "1105792", "An Empirical Analysis of the Gender Gap in Mathematics"
)), row.names = c(NA, 27L), class = "data.frame")
```

I will also ad a link to the file I'm currently working with:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwaimr21eld2jg6/relevant.csv?dl=0
```

Please note that one of the values for "category" reads "AN: Perspectives from a Cluster Analysis[...]" and that this value is incorrect. I have not yet managed to grep/delete this entry and I'm just too tired right now, sorry about that.

Comment: Is "TI:" always the first in the sequence?

Comment: Assuming the sequence is complete, then yes. But as you can see in the first entry, TI will sometimes be missing.

Comment: Are you saying "AN:" is  never missing?

Comment: Can you please post some data with missing entries?

Comment: I hope not. It's the most frequently occuring variable, bar none. In order to answer that questoin I would first have to distribute each variable value to the correct sequence, and I don'n really kjnow how to do that!

Comment: @tmfmnk I would love to but I don't know how to search for them (and if I could I would be halfway to a solution.). The material is garguntean and I would pretty much have to look through all of it manually, hoping to find a sequence with missing entries.

Comment: I think it is very difficult to find a general solution to your problem as it is not clear whether any variable is present in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on *"Every sequence (or so I gather) will end with Article Number (AN). Apart from this, variables/variable values seem to be missing pretty much at random"* I am assuming that `"AN:"` is never missing -

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    ID = cumsum(category == "AN:") - (category == "AN:") + 1
  ) %>% 
  spread(category, value)

# A tibble: 4 x 10
     ID `AF:`     `AN:`  `AU:`            `AV:`        `DT:`    `IS:` `PY:` `SO:`                 `TI:`                        
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>            <chr>        <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>                 <chr>                        
1     1 MIT       10943~ Duflo, Esther    http://www.~ Journal~ 1945~ 2010  American Economic Jo~ <NA>                         
2     2 NBER; NB~ 10757~ Freeman, Richar~ http://www.~ Journal~ 1945~ 2010  American Economic Jo~ Prize Structure and Informat~
3     3 U MI; Co~ 11057~ Bound, John; Lo~ http://www.~ Journal~ 1945~ 2010  American Economic Jo~ Why Have College Completion ~
4     4 <NA>      <NA>   <NA>             <NA>         <NA>     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>                  An Empirical Analysis of the~
```

---

#### Note -

Here's a way to test if "AN:" is a good indicator for end of sequence - Below code counts the rows between consecutive "AN:". If all intervals are `<= 9` then it returns `FALSE` which means that "AN:" is a good indicator for end of sequences. If not, then I'd suggest hosting the actual file somewhere so that people can look at the whole dataset.

```
df %>% 
  group_split(ID = cumsum(category == "AN:") - (category == "AN:") + 1) %>% 
  sapply(nrow) %>% 
  {any(. > 9)}

[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the first part. We create "ID" as the cumulative sum of the umber of "AN"s so far. And the +1 is probably just there so the ID can start at one. But what does the "- (category == "AN:")" mean?

Comment: `cumsum(category == "AN:")` puts every `AN:` in the next group so `- (category == "AN:")` pulls it back 1 group. Just remove the `-` part and check `ID` results for the difference. This adjustment is not needed when we work with start of a sequence but here we are forced to work with end of sequence.

Comment: It returns TRUE but I will mark this as the answer nonetheless, since it would have worked had my presuppositions been correct.

Can I somehow "grep" a sequence of strings so I can separate the correct sequences from the rest?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the data. If you add a link to the data in your post I will take a look when I get home. Generally speaking if we don't know that start or end of sequence then any solution will just be a best guess. Accuracy is not guaranteed.

Comment: Another idea...if I create an data frame 9 column and try to populate it via a FOR-loop? I would basically need an If/then statement for each column, and I need to create a counter for which row to read from in the source frame (set value=value if category is match and increment by one, else set value = NA....

Oh god it's like 0:30 AM I should tend to my much suffering social life.

Comment: I downloaded your data. Let's continue this on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197701/how-to-deal-with-messy-data-with-variables-not-marked-as-missing)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you call that dataset `dt`:

```
library(tidyverse)
dt %>% mutate(Sequence = cumsum(row_number() == 1 | lag(category) == 'AN:')) %>% 
    group_by(Sequence) %>% 
    mutate(seq_ind = row_number(), n = n()) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    arrange(desc(n), seq_ind) %>% #This will put sequences with the most number of fields first
    mutate(category = as_factor(category)) %>% #column orders are defined based on the order of the largest sequence
    select(-seq_ind, -n) %>% 
    spread(key = category, value = value)
```